# Magicento not worked fine in PHPStorm IDE

Tags: magento, phpstorm

I recently installed PHPStorm and Magicento plugin to develop new magento extension but 
it doesn't works fine for me when i press ( alt + M ) it say that Magicento is disabled, when i check it in the plugins It's enabled (It's trail version )

[image: below is screenshot picture]

And this Magicento configuration

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have enabled Magicento for the current projet ?
The second screenshot seem to be "Template Project Settings" and not "Projet Settings [YOURPROJECT]".

Try going into Project Settings with CTRL+ALT+S or File -> Settings".

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help it works fine.  in mac os there is no file --> setting path .. there is file --> default setting      and also CTRL+ALT+S   but i use CTRL+SHFT+A to fine current project settings